# "..and however they like each other." Does the meaning change with commas?

Tags: punctuation

Does "and however they like each other" mean "doesn't matter how much or how they like each other?
And if you add commas "and, however, they like each other", then it means as "despite that/although"

Answer (score -1):

The meaning does change with the addition of commas, although the meaning might be difficult to establish without the context of surrounding sentences.

For example, if the passage was:

> Anne and Bob are critical to this team, and however they like each other, they need to work together.

the meaning becomes "doesn't matter how much or how they like each other". In my opinion, the sentence flows a bit better with the addition of "much" after "however", as in "however much they like each other".

If the passage is instead:

> Anne and Bob are critical to this team, and, however, they like each other, they need to work together.

it no longer makes grammatical sense. I would say that the combination of "and" and "however" doesn't make sense in most contexts, since "and" and "however" are conjuctions that serve different purposes. Instead, you might say something like:

> Anne and Bob need to work together. However, they like each other, so it should be easy for them to do so.